# cache a rest server index request

Tags: caching, services, 8

I created one custom module for rest server, i created own resources and i want to be able to cache index request, for return a 304 with using http request if - headers.

I cannot find information on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I did it setting my own headers (cache-control, last-modified, etag, expires), and setting rules for delete cache.